# Stop subscriber (sink) from running multiple times

Tags: swift, combine

In my `CoordinatesViewModel` file i have function `addWaypoint` that gets called when user presses the button. In `LocationManager` file i have function that gets users location and then stops receiving location updates. To access location from `LocationManager` file i use `.sink` (i am new to Swift so i don’t know if `.sink` is the right way about doing this). Now the problem i noticed is that `.sink` sometimes runs twice or more so the same result gets added to array. This usually happens the second time i press the button.

Here is the example what i get from `print` into console when i run the app:

```
hello from ViewModel
hello from LocationManager
hello from ViewModel
```

LocationManager:

```
    private let manager = CLLocationManager()
    @Published var userWaypoint: CLLocation? = nil
 
    override init(){
        super.init()
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.delegate = self
    }

    func getCurrentUserWaypoint(){
        wasWaypointButtonPressed = true
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let userWaypoint = locations.last  else {return}
        print("hello from LocationManager")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.userWaypoint = userWaypoint
        }
        self.manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

CoordinatesViewModel:

```
private let locationManager: LocationManager
var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
@Published var waypoints: [CoordinateData] = []


init() {
    locationManager = LocationManager()
}

func addWaypoint(){
    locationManager.getCurrentUserWaypoint()
    cancellable = locationManager.$userWaypoint.sink{ userWaypoint in
        if let userWaypoint = userWaypoint{
            print("hello from ViewModel")
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                let newWaypoint = CoordinateData(coordinates: userWaypoint.coordinate)
                self.waypoints.append(newWaypoint)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to receive one value you can use:

```
func first() -> Publishers.First<Self>`
```

> Publishes the first element of a stream, then finishes.

Because `$userWaypoint` publishes `CLLocation?` you also need to use:

```
func compactMap<T>((Self.Output) -> T?) -> Publishers.CompactMap<Self, T>
```

> Calls a closure with each received element and publishes any returned optional that has a value.

With all of the above:

```
cancellable = locationManager
    .$userWaypoint
    .compactMap { $0 } // remove nils
    .first() // ensure that only one value gets emitted
    .map { CoordinateData(coordinates: $0.coordinate) } // map to the type you need
    .receive(on: RunLoop.main) // switch to the main thread
    .sink { [weak self] waypoint in
        self?.waypoints.append(waypoint)
    }
```

Comment: This did remove duplicates from array, but i noticed that when i insert the second waypoint it has the same coordinates as the first waypoint even though location changed.

Comment: I don’t think I know enough about your project to be able to say why.

Answer (score 0):

First of all rather than dispatching the result to the main thread insert the Combine operator

```
.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
```

You could simply `cancel` the pipeline after getting the first result

---

For a *one-shot-publisher* I recommend a different approach with Swift Concurrency. The `Continuation` allows to adopt `async/await` in a delegate environment

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    enum LocationError : Error {  case noLocationFound }
    
    private let manager = CLLocationManager()
    
    private var locationContinuation: CheckedContinuation<CLLocation, Error>?
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.delegate = self
    }
    
    func getCurrentUserWaypoint() async throws -> CLLocation {
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            locationContinuation = continuation
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let userWaypoint = locations.last else {
            locationContinuation?.resume(throwing: LocationError.noLocationFound)
            return
        }
        print("hello from LocationManager")
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        locationContinuation?.resume(returning: userWaypoint)
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        locationContinuation?.resume(throwing: error)
    }
}
```

And `CoordinateViewModel` is

```
@MainActor
class CoordinateViewModel : ObservableObject {
    private let locationManager: LocationManager
    @Published var waypoints: [CoordinateData] = []

    init() {
        locationManager = LocationManager()
    }

    func addWaypoint(){
        Task {
            do {
                let newLocation = try await locationManager.getCurrentUserWaypoint()
                print("hello from ViewModel")
                self.waypoints.append(CoordinateData(coordinates: newLocation.coordinate))
            } catch {
                print(error) // show it to the user
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another benefit is that you don't need to care about the main thread, the `@MainActor` does it on your behalf.

Always handle errors and show them to the user.